# JQuery offset #NaN issue

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a fixed menu bar at top of the page and all menu links are anchor links on the same page. In short, it's a one page website divided in sections with anchor links as menu items.

I am using the javascript below for smooth slide to section when menu items are clicked.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("a.anchorLink").anchorAnimate()
});

jQuery.fn.anchorAnimate = function(settings) {

    settings = jQuery.extend({
        speed : 1100
    }, settings);   

    return this.each(function(){
        var caller = this
        $(caller).click(function (event) {  
            event.preventDefault()
            var locationHref = window.location.href
            var elementClick = $(caller).attr("href")

            var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top-60;
            $("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, settings.speed, function() {
                window.location.hash = elementClick-60
            });
            return false;
        })
    })
}
```

Since the top menu height is 60 pixels, I need to subtract it from offset().top to ensure slide works properly. I also have to subtract in location hash else there is a jerky slide (in FF and IE, works fine in Chrome) once the slide on click in complete.

It works great but the problem is the URL is shown as http://www.site.com/#NaN instead of http://www.site.com/#linkname

Here is the full code - http://jsfiddle.net/85saK/1/. Unfortunately, it won't show you the URL after click which ends with #NaN instead of the actual link ID, e.g #store, #home or #contact.

Comment: Have you looked at what `$(caller).attr("href")` gives you? The string that it returns cannot be directly coerced into a number, thus when you try to subtract 60 from it (for whatever reason I don't know) you get `NaN` - Not a Number

Comment: @YiJiang Please run the code after removing "-60" from elementClick in firefox. You'll understand why I have no option other than this.

Comment: You do realize what is happening here, right? That the reason why your code is "working" is because you broke it. Please, read up about [how to manipulate the browser's history](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Manipulating_the_browser_history), or more simply, edit the style such that the element's size extents upwards by 60px

Comment: I understand what is NaN error and I perfectly know why it's coming. I need to know how I can work it around to show URL with correct anchor link. I would prefer the CSS approach though I am not really sure what you meant by "element's size extents upwards by 60px" and how it would help.

Comment: I understand why you are subtracting 60 here: `var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top-60;`, but why here: `window.location.hash = elementClick-60`

Comment: Please run the code (http://jsfiddle.net/85saK/1/) after removing "-60" from elementClick in firefox. It doesn't slide properly in that case.

Comment: @Vikram SIf you understand what's causing it, then you understand enough to know that including it in the title would only cause confusion, which is happening here. You can include an `a` element and shift it up by `60px` using CSS. You could add a `60px` top padding to the element then give the previous element a negative bottom margin to pull it up, or you could have a wrapper with `overflow:hidden` to hide it. There are a lot of ways to do this.

Comment: @YiJiang I already tried negative margin but that caused other issues. Anyways looks like CSS is the way to go. Thanks!

Comment: @YiJiang I tried all of these but none of them helps in getting rid of the jerky motion. Guess I would have to live with it.

Comment: I've not understand the problem, but i think is better - $('#menu').height() than -60.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
var destination = $(elementClick).offset().top -60;
$("html:not(:animated),body:not(:animated)").animate({ scrollTop: destination}, settings.speed, function() {
    //window.location.hash = elementClick
    elementClick
});
```

Comment: Great. Though it doesn't fix the issue the way I wanted but it certainly helps a lot by removing the #NaN from the URL and keeping the functionality intact. Thanks!